# How to validate nested objects in Vuelidate?

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I use Vuelidate in my project and have the following form:

```
data () {
  return {
    form: {
      title: undefined,
      users: [{
        name: undefined,
        age: undefined,
      }],
    },
  };
},
```

I configured validation rules for the "form.title" like so:

```
validations () {
  return {
    form: {
      title: {
        required,
      },
    },
  };
},
```

Now, I also need to configure validation for the "form.users" array of objects.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

We can validate arrays of objects using the `forEach` helper.

```
import { helpers, required } from '@vuelidate/validators';
```

The following code works for me with Vuelidate v2.0.0:

```
validations () {
  return {
    form: {
      users: {
        $each: helpers.forEach({
          name: {
            required,
          },
          age: {
            required,
          },
        }),
      },
    },
  };
},
```

Comment: How to do that with the Components/Collection api for the Options API?